# SQL Server After Update Trigger Not firing

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Kindly help, I have been trying to create an update trigger to insert data into a specific table once it's updated with a certain value. "Accepted". for somewhat reason the trigger is not firing

```js
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TRGIU_CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTrigger') = 1)
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGIU_CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGIU_CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT] ON [dbo].[CLEARING_BATCH]               
AFTER INSERT                
AS                

IF UPDATE(QM_STATUS)                
BEGIN                
  Declare @QM_Status Varchar(12),                
          @QM_Status_Old Varchar(12),                
          @Submission_Pk Uniqueidentifier            
                
  SELECT @QM_Status = I.QM_STATUS,                
         @QM_Status_old = D.QM_STATUS,                
         @Submission_Pk = I.PK               
         --@Lab_used = LE.ID                            
    FROM CLEARING_BATCH CB                
    LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_RESULT SR ON CB.PK = SR.PPK                 
    JOIN INSERTED I ON SR.PK = I.PPK                 
    JOIN DELETED D ON I.PK = D.PK 

             
  IF(@QM_Status = 'Accepted' and (@QM_Status <> @QM_Status_old or @QM_Status_old is null))                
  
  
  begin

  INSERT INTO BATCH(PPK,BATCH_ID)

  SELECT CB.PK,CB.BATCH_ID
  FROM LABORATORY L
  JOIN CLEARING_BATCH CB ON L.PK = CB.PPK
  JOIN CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT CSR ON CB.PK = CSR.PPK
  LEFT JOIN BATCH B ON CB.PK = B.PPK
  WHERE B.PPK IS NULL
 

  UPDATE BATCH
  SET BATCH_ID = CB.BATCH_ID

  FROM BATCH B
  JOIN CLEARING_BATCH CB ON B.PPK = CB.PPK

  END
  end
  GO
```

Comment: Add an insert into an arbitrary audit table to just see what is being fired, i.e. before your IF, to see that the IF is not stopping the code being run.  Possibly even add more then one insert to see where it is being "thrown" out.

Comment: @BethuelMhiongo, shouldn't the trigger be AFTER UPDATE in your case?

Comment: YOu've defined an `AFTER INSERT` trigger - this will fire after any **`INSERT`** - not an `UPDATE` ! You need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger...

Comment: Also your code seems to assume that all operations will affect only one row. If three rows are affected by the operation, what value do you expect for `@QM_Status`? The "first" row, the "last" row, the "middle" row, random, ...?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne after I added the insert into arbitary audit table, i was able to see that the trigger was firing when the QM_Status changed to 'Accepted' the only issue was that it was not inserting the data for the insert statements. However i managed to resolve that by fixing up my Joins and refining my where condition. Eduard & marc_s thanks for the heads-up

Comment: @BethuelMhlongo Glad it helped.  You are welcome to mark the comment as helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an **`AFTER INSERT`** trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGIU_CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT] 
ON [dbo].[CLEARING_BATCH]               
AFTER INSERT                
AS
```

which will fire after any `INSERT` statement that **inserts** new rows - this will **NOT** be fired when you `UPDATE` something!

If you want to capture the `UPDATE` operations, you need an **`AFTER UPDATE`** trigger instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGIU_CLEARING_SAMPLE_RESULT] 
ON [dbo].[CLEARING_BATCH]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
   ....
```